# Declared object cannot be resolved

Tags: java, object, user-interface, scope

I want to build a Moneytransfer GUI, there are lots of errors for variable accessing I want to correct it, going to make variables in Transfer private and use get-set methods for them.Here are my 2 classes MoneyTR_GUI ( http://codepad.org/hRDso3WB ) and Transfer ( http://codepad.org/bVVqDIOv ) When I want to fix the first error I created an object so I can use the set method with

```
Transfer TR1 = new Transfer();
```

Line 74, this gives me a warning your variable is not being used ...
I want to use it at line 121 but it tells TR1 cannot be resolved...But it recognizes TR2 which is declared one line above...So I think because they are in different code blocks the recognition fails.Although all errors the code delivers a GUI when compiled, you can see for yourself, for now I want to create a Transfer object when the button Transfer is clicked and later of course do lots of computations with that object, how can I achieve this?Or is this not possible and I shall use static variables?I would appreciate your time!

Comment: TR1 is declared in the anonymous' classes method. That's its scope. You cannot access it from outside that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an anonymous ActionListener with the method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Transfer TR1 = new Transfer();
    transferday_nroftransfer.setEditable(false);
}
```

Here `TR1` is declared and initialized but never used (so you get the warning). It has method scope. When this method is called and returns, the reference `TR1` no longer exists. If you want to keep a reference to it, you will want to add an instance variable to your class.

Comment: "you will want to add an instance variable to your class." class = MoneyTR_GUI? Because in class Transfer transfer_id variable already exists...

Comment: @Anarkie If you need it in the class `MoneyTR_GUI`, then you need an instance variable (or more than one) in that class.

Comment: Then I should combine both classes and make one?

Comment: @Anarkie You really shouldn't. In your class `MoneyTR_GUI`, you have a field `private JFrame frame;`. In the same manner, add a field `private Transfer TR1;`. Also, java naming conventions state that fields should start with lowercase and should probably be more descriptive. Try `private Transfer transfer1;`